Examples of expressions with coefficient that depends on parameters of physical system
When I read about derivation of equation for space-time intervals in Special Relativity I encountered with the following equation:
$ds'=k(V)ds$
I read that coefficient $k$ depends on magnitude of relative velocity $V$.
Are there another examples of expressions with coefficient that depends on parameters of physical system?
Could anyone give such examples or hint?
Thanks.
